# Motorcycle not preforming under load

Tags: acceleration

I have a 1994 Honda shadow dual carb. The bike idles great and revs awesome in neutral, when I ride in first it preforms as usual.

When I shift into any other gear the bike Boggs down. I have gotten mixed signals in my research if it is a carb issue or an electrical issue. I recently changed the tank to a smaller tank using the same petcock which is gravity fed. I’m not sure if the smaller tank can affect the way the gas lines are connected to provide proper fuel flow. Any help would be great

Comment: It sounds like a carb issue to me so that's where I'd look first.  Are you sure the carbs are not clogged from sitting with old gasoline?  It's also possible you do have fuel flow problem.  Are you sure your new lines are not pinched or clogged?

Comment: It may be worth looking at your timing.